# Both their three cars

Tags: pronouns, ambiguity, possessives, determiners

> **Both** indicates that the action or state denoted by the verb applies *individually to each* of two entities. *Both books weigh more
> than five pounds* means that **each** weighs more than five by
> itself, not that the two books weighed together come to more than five.
>
> https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=both

Is *both their three cars* ambiguous with the meaning "each owns three cars, six cars in total"?

What about *the three cars **of both**(**'s**?)* or ***both's** three cars*?

BOTH (OED) https://www.oed.com/oed2/00025622

Comment: I do not know a meaning for "both their three cars".  My impression is: a non-native speaker, meaning "all three of their cars".

Comment: This is gibberish

Comment: Could you please construct a sentence in which *both their three cars* could mean *"each owns three cars, six cars in total"*?

Comment: @HotLicks Can't _both their six cars_ be used for two people who has two and four cars respectively?

Comment: @GJC - Yes, you can write that if your intent is to write gibberish.

Answer (score 2):

"Both their three cars" sounds really wrong because "both" typically modifies the noun following it: "both" modifies "books" in the sentence from ahdictionary. In the phrase "both their three cars" at first glance it looks as if "both" is modifying "cars" but then it is specified that there are three cars, making the phrasing confusing. To indicate that the "both" is modifying two people referred to previously, you would need to use "they both".

For example, instead of "Both their three cars needed an oil change," you could use "They both had three cars in need of an oil change" or "They both had three cars that needed an oil change."

Answer (score 0):

The word *both* requires the referent of the noun phrase it combines with to be exactly two. So when you say:

1. I like both of the cars.
2. I like both (of) their cars.

the sentence is only felicitous in a context in which there are only two relevant cars.

So sentences like your example is simply ungrammatical, since the 'three' in the noun phrase is incompatible with the requirement that the noun phrase refers to two things.

3. *I like both of the three cars.
4. *I like both (of) their three cars.

With respect to your second pair of examples (which as given aren't actually grammatical) we can construct examples like:

5. The three cars of both of them
6. The three cars of them both.

These examples aren't that great, but my interpretation of them is that they mean that each person has three cars, so six cars in total. I'm not sure if there is an interpretation in which there are three cars which belong to them both collectively.

Comment: Would you say then that 'The guards took all ten men prisoner, binding both their hands and feet' is unacceptable?

Comment: The requirement is that the object of "both" can be easily divided into two groups or entities, e.g. "Since omnivores hunt and are hunted, they can be both predators and prey." https://www.nationalgeographic.org/encyclopedia/omnivores/

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Of course not. :) But the relevant referent here is 'hands and feet' not the internal parts of them.  Care to suggest a better wording?

Comment: 'Referent' is the material, real-world entity referred to, not the noun / NP, the words used to describe. // I'm still exploring the possibility of the acceptability of 'We know both their faults, and they are many' for 'We know the faults of both of them, and they are many'.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence is clear enough. The problem is that “their three cars” has to be clear in the reader’s mind before the expression with “both” can be effective. Otherwise it’s just confusing.

There are many ways the sentence could be made to work.

For example, here’s a link to one of many sites that offer “three car haulers”.
https://www.suncountrytrailers.com/3-car-haulers/

One can easily imagine a context where two drivers are each towing one of these rigs, and have something happen to them at the same time.

*Both* is a strong grouping concept. For example, consider a description of two families and their children:

- *Both their boys* is easy to visualize, even if nothing has been previouly said about the children’s sexes. We all have examples in our minds to draw from.
- *Both their twins* is harder to visualize without some prior information about the children being twins. Twins are less common in our experience.
- *Both their triplets* seems (to me at least) much harder to visualize from the words alone.  Triplets are quite rare.

An expression like “Both their three _______” works best when the three things form a group that the reader can visualize, e.g. “Bob and Ted split the six-pack. Both their three beers were downed immediately.”

Comment: Can't _both their six cars_ be used for two people who has two and four cars respectively?

Comment: @GJC  You can use ambiguous expressions like *both their six cars* any way you like. However, their meaning to the reader has be established either by something in the preceding text, or by prior knowledge the reader can safely be assumed to have. The more unusual the meaning (as in your example), the more preparation must be done by the writer.